# Debugging third party installed node module

Tags: node.js, debugging, console.log

Appreciate inputs to debug easily and effectively an already installed third party node module (say `mkdirp` or `expressjs` ...)

I looked at [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) but looks like it can debug only direct scripts (like `node-debug myscript.js`).

But for my case, I want to debug the installed module directly when i use it in the terminal. For example, when i run the `browserify` in the terminal using `browserify main.js -o bundle.js`, i want to start debugging the `browserify` module code.

Currently placing `console.log` statements in the third party code which is very painful.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously an older question, but for anyone else who stumbles across this question, you can debug just by getting node to launch the module directly, so I think you could do something like:

```
node-debug node_modules/browersify/bin/browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

I was personally using vscode trying to debug tslint, and there I created a debug configuration like this:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\tslint\\bin\\tslint",
      "args": [
        "-c",
        "tslint.json",
        "-p",
        "tsconfig.json"
      ]
    }
```